# Error when launching signed and notarized app - JavaScript error occurred in the main process

Tags: electron, knex.js, electron-forge

When launching an electronjs app that has been osx signed and notarized with electron-forge I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Knex: run
$ npm install sqlite3 --save
dlopen(/var/folders/..., 0x0001): tried: '/var/folders/....' (code signature in <> '.....' not valid for use in process: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs), '......' (no such file)
```

I'm using electron-forge to make the project. Signing and Notarization succeeds. If I do not sign and notarize the application launches and functions properly.